# Store each line on single array field

Tags: arrays, bash, path

My problem is:

In my bash script the command.

```
ls -d */ | sed 's#/##'
```

shows me all folders in current path like:

```
dir1
new folder2
folder3
new directory 4
```

now i need to store those in a array but the problem is that "new folder2" will cover 2 array fields, i need to store every line in a single field.
So that:

```
var[0] = "dir1"
var[1] = "new folder2"
var[2] = "folder3"
var[3] = "new directory 4"
```

How to achieve that?

Comment: **do not parse the output of `ls`**. Never.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an array with each folder of the current directory. It's really that simple:

```
shopt -s nullglob
var=(*/)
```

If you then decide you need to strip the trailing slash from the array members, it's better to do so when you iterate over them, or output them to the user. As long as you work with globs – which is what `*/` is – you're going to be pretty safe without the need to manipulate strings.

Good to read:

- [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)
- [Nullglob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/NullGlob)

Comment: Referring to the answer linked above, I fail to understand that you couldn't _educate_ the OP that the trailing `/` could've been easily removed using `find ... -printf`.  Moreover, did you know that your approach wouldn't quite work in there were newlines in filesname.

Comment: @devnull Indeed you could remove the character with `-printf` when you use `find`, but that's really just useful for outputting to the terminal. And again, you'd run into issues with "strange characters" if you will. Other than that, the OP primarily needs to get an array of directories as far as I can tell, for which a simple glob is sufficient. My solution does work with newlines in directory names under Bash and Zsh.

Comment: If I could `+1` you again, I would. `:)`.